# Recovering contacts from a backup in w10m

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, microsoft-account, accounts

I accidentally removed an account from my w10m and most of my contact disappeared from People app.

How can I recover them? I have a number of backups on my OneDrive.

Thanks.

Comment: You removed your Microsoft account? Have you tried adding it back?

Comment: I can't remember username and password. On the old phone is still active, the only thing I know is that it's called Outlook...

Comment: Then you should [reset your MS account password](https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx). Not remembering it can bite you again in the future. The backups won't help you - to use them you'll need to do a hard reset and sign in to the same account before you can restore from them.

Comment: Now I know where it is. It's a live.com account. I recovered the password and logged-in and I can see all my contacts. It was created ages ago. I cannot add it to my lumia 950 because it's linked to the same email address of my main Microsoft account. How can I do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying there. Do you have multiple MS accounts? What do you mean by " it's linked to the same email address of my main Microsoft account"?

Comment: Yes, a live.com account based on the same email address of the MS account already configured on the lumia 950. Is it possible to move contacts between accounts? I could create a new one based on a different email address and afterward add it.

Comment: If you can log in to both accounts, then you can export the contacts from one account and import them to the other. Go to https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/people and click on Manage in the top menu bar, the options are there. If you need more help, though, I suggest you try http://webapps.stackexchange.com, this is getting a bit off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Indrek: Solved exporting to *.csv and creating `firstname_lastname@outlook.com` new account, importing *.csv and adding this new account to Lumia 950. With different e-mail address there was no problem. Add an answer so I can mark this solved.

Comment: Not sure why you didn't import to the account that's already configured on your Lumia instead of creating yet another one, but if it worked for you... Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the backups, you'd need to do a hard reset (which wipes everything on your phone), then log in to the same MS account and restore from the backup. If you have multiple MS accounts and one of them is working on your phone, you can copy the contacts over. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Log in at https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/people with the account that contains the contacts.
   If you don't remember your password, go to https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx
2. In the top menu bar, click on Manage → Export contacts. Follow the steps to save the contacts to a file.
3. Repeat step 1, but log in with the other account that's configured on your Lumia.
4. In the top menu bar, click on Manage → Import contacts. Follow the steps to import the file you saved earlier.
5. Allow some time for the phone to sync the account, and the contacts should show up on your phone again.