# How to back up contacts and messages without MS account?

Tags: microsoft-account

So, after I got my Nokia Lumia 520 back from repair (on warranty!), they updated my phone (and deleted all my personal data, what a bunch of ...nevermind).
And as I got it back (I think it was January 2015) I couldn't download any app anymore without logging in using windows account. Before that update, there was a possibility to do so, without logging in.
And after I had it enough, after I got back my phone, I just used something such as "dasdasdasd@windows.com" and something simmiliar as password...I was able to install few applications. After that, it asked me again for password and (ofcourse!) I couldn't remember it at all. And now I decided it's time to "repair" phone and I really wish to set it to factory setting, but before doing that, I want to copy my contacts (and if messages possible too) and save them..I don't want to re-type every one of them, there might be over 100 of them.
Anyone knows, what could I possibly do to solve this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Related: [Recovering contacts from a backup in w10m](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/14092/1401)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: You will need another Nokia or Windows Phone for this method to work.

First, you will have to install the '[Transfer My Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/transfer-my-data/9wzdncrfj3dr)' app from the Windows Store.

Using a Nokia Phone:

1. On your Nokia, go to Contacts > Options > Copy Contacts > Another Device.
2. On your Lumia, turn on Bluetooth and stay visible (Settings > Bluetooth)
3. Select Choose > Copy to > Phone. Accept the pairing request on your Lumia.
4. Start the transfer process. Wait for it to complete.
5. When its time to re-transfer the contacts, open Transfer My Data on your Lumia.
6. Pair your phones using bluetooth and tick copy contacts on your Lumia.
7. Start the process and wait for it to complete.
   (Unfortunately, I didnt find a way to transfer messages)

Using another Windows Phone:

1. Download and install Transfer My Data app on both devices.
2. Pair them via bluetooth and open Transfer My Data on the other Lumia.
3. Tick 'Copy Contacts' and 'Copy messages'. Start the process and wait for the process to finish.
4. When its time to re-transfer, do the same process but using your Lumia.

Give me an upvote if it helped. Ask me in comments if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can backup both contacts and messages using [contacts + message backup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm) app.Contacts + Message Backup app is a Settings app that enables you to make backup of all your contacts (in VCF format) and messages (SMS & MMS including attachments) to SD card (in XML format) for later restore to same or another Windows Phone.Backup is stored in 'backup+restore' folder on the SD card.
Just follow screen instructions and you'll be done. Considering that you are facing problems installing  apps from the store, here is the link where you can have the xap file for the app.

https://www.appx4fun.com/apps/12561/

Known Issue: Restoring a backup of messages from a dual SIM Windows Phone restores all messages to message store for the first SIM/slot. To use this app, please go to Settings on your Windows Phone. This app will NOT appear in your list of installed apps.

Comment: You probably didn't noticed, that I cannot install any app on it, because I cannot access to microsoft account. Please read the text before.

Comment: I also had given the link where you can have the xap file for the app considering that you are facing problems installing apps from the store. Can you install the app withh the xap file?

Comment: No, there's no way I could do this.